# Vue | Call method function inside of data

Tags: vue.js

Stack.

---

### The problem | [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZropZJ)

I have this code in Vue:

```
<input v-model="name" type="text"/>
<span>{{ slug }}</span>
```

And this data:

```
data: {
   name: ''
}
```

This is methods:

```
computed: {
  slug: function() {
     return this.slugify(this.name);
  }

slugify: function(name) {
  var slug = name.toLowerCase();
  slug = slug.replace(/\s*$/g, '');
  slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

  return slug;
}
```

How can I use {{ slug }} in input value?

v-bind:value is not working together with v-model as Vue Docs said.

---

### The question

I need to generate slug inside another input?

It will be look like:

```
<input v-model="name" type="text"/>
<input v-model="slug" type="text"/> <--- Here goes generated input with value = slug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for this would be like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: '',
    slug: ''
  },
  methods: {
    slugify: function () {
      let slugInput = this.title.toLowerCase()
      slugInput = slugInput.replace(/\s*$/g, '');
      slugInput = slugInput.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

      this.slug = slugInput
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <input 
          v-model="title" 
          type="text"
          @input="slugify"/>

   <span>{{ title }}</span>

  <br>

     <input 
          v-model="slug" 
          type="text"/>

   <span>{{ slug }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Work's perfectly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to stick with v-model, then modify name in situ with @keypress and @blur, **[like this...](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQGbNz)**

**code**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: '',
    name:''
  },
  computed: {
    slug: function() {
      return this.slugify(this.name);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onkeypress(){
      console.log("change");
      var slug = this.name.toLowerCase();
      slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
      this.name = slug
    },
    onblur(){
      this.name = slugify(this.name)      
    },
    slugify: function(name) {
      var slug = name.toLowerCase();
      slug = slug.replace(/\s*$/g, '');
      slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

      return slug;
    }
  }
});
```

**markup**

```
<div id="app">
   <input v-model="name"@keypress="onkeypress" @blur="onblur" type="text"/>
   <span>{{ slug }}</span>
</div>
```